# Is it possible to search patents by assignee?

Tags: uspto, search

My name is Jesse L Culpepper. I would like to know how many patents are in my name.

Comment: By the way, assignee does not equal the inventor. I'm the inventor on over 80 patents but the assignee on none of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can check them using various patent search websites. under applicant, inventors, assignee heads. for more information please visit-

http://application.epo.org/wbt/espacenet/assistant.php?lg=en

For example European Patent office provides [Link](http://worldwide.espacenet.com/advancedSearch?locale=en_EP)

wherein a researcher can enter keywords designed with name and find patents listed under that term

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am able to find 6 patents with "Jesse L Culpepper" as the claimed inventor: https://patents.google.com/?inventor=Jesse+L.+Culpepper