# How to find all patents of inventor and get automatic update

Tags: search, patent-search

I was trying to get a list of my patents for updating my CV/resume and because of my common name searching scholar.google.com  and/or usto or other websites I get 100+ patents out of which only <10 are mine, is there an easy way to get a list of only my patent ?

Even better can it be a live list so I can put the list on my website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are vast method to cover all patents filed by inventor, It depends on indexing of database, truncation or errors made while filing or indexing, language etc.

A person has to design various keywords to cover all possibilities. Still researcher may not get complete information if patent office is not included in searchable database.

To search inventor you can visit ["Is it possible to search patents by assignee?"](https://patents.stackexchange.com/a/11954/11895)

You may include Family Patents of results ["Is this patent valid in USA or Australia?"](https://patents.stackexchange.com/a/12153/11895)

To Get Automatic update if new patents are listed on your search term You need to have RSS reader. To get update you need to click on RSS icon as below image and subscribe the same-

[image]