# How do I find out where MY patents are?

Tags: ownership

Name is Travis Jay Vincent... I would like to know. I know I have many. Where can I search?...Please and Thank you

Comment: duplicate of [search inventor assignee](http://patents.stackexchange.com/a/11954/11895)

Answer (score 0):

Visit here, put your name, select "Inventor Name" from the tab, and search.
http://patft.uspto.gov/netahtml/PTO/index.html

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer your direction are correct but limited to US patents only, further steps are slightly confusing could you elaborate in details so that a proper answer can be made?